# is it possible to add my customized indoor map using google map sdk for my android app?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to develop an app using rssi of ble,wifi to set position of my users in indoor environment, or something else for example when they are near specific location send theme notification.
I have to add my information and markers to google map. and my own simple map.
it is like customized map for my users in my app.

I have this place in map but I want to add walking path and more information.

right now it does not have anything. no walking path for example.no stores information and exact location.

[image]

and i want add something like these or much simpler:

[Sample indoor map 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Sz8.png)
[Sample indoor map 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XILvE.png)

as I see you mentioned indoor map is just available for certain country. 
this link : [are available in select locations](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685827)

and again you mentioned : Display a floor plan as a [ground overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay) or [tile overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay) on your map. This will enable only users of your application to view your floor plans.

my country is not the part of your supported list (sanction). but the google maps app is still working here.
I just want using google map to be shown with my customized map and information,markers just for my users in my app not public.
is it possible ?

I place my beacon and the position of the user is set by my algorithm in map. I do not know that I'm in right way or not. where I should start?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Google Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) to create a map in your android app. You can customize the map on this sdk like putting [markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker), [info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows), [styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling) etc.

At high zoom levels, the map shows floor plans for indoor spaces which are available in select locations you mentioned.

As stated in the Maps SDK for Android [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#add_floor_plans) -  If floor plan data is not available for a building that you would like to highlight in your application, you can:

1. [Add floor plans](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/) to Google Maps directly. This will make your floor plans available to all users of Google Maps.
2. Display a floor plan as a ground overlay or tile overlay on your map. This will enable only users of your application to view your floor plans.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much . I saw that . As i searched again i realize maybe i need to work with offline map at first starting app in android. Save a little part the map with overlay. For example the amusement park. I mean no network connection . in this case google map is gonna never load. Have you heard about openstreetmap? I see it has offline (save map in apk file) and ground overlay function.

Comment: Hello @NimaAzhd Is this same can we achieve for Flutter or in Ios?

Comment: @JaiminModi Hi. I worked osm on android kotlin. It is written in java for java and kotlin platform. You have to check their GitHub.  about indoor maps , I searched about indoor maps 3 years ago. as I found out you could have two scenarios for implementing indoor map with BLE or other technologies. 
1- using some indoor company's SDK. (you have to paid) they can do easily most of the things for your. 
2-implement everything you need. for example have deep knowledge in the language or platform your are working on. (java-kotlin-flutter). you have to work with osm map and could customized .

Comment: @JaiminModi  I sense it might does not give you the result you want to work with tiles or overlay in osm. I tried it and I realize complexity in tiles and image overlay . it might not be good for industry or real world application. I don't know exactly it is standard way to achieve this. search the android osm GitHub issue about "tiles" "overlays" "customized map" . see some questions and read their complete documentation. if you get a good result share it.
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

I recommend you look at some paid services that work on indoor maps.